# linear-regression with torch7 demo

Tags: lua, machine-learning, linear-regression, deep-learning, torch

I am following this demo-
https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/master/linear-regression/example-linear-regression.lua

```
feval = function(x_new)
   -- set x to x_new, if differnt
   -- (in this simple example, x_new will typically always point to x,
   -- so the copy is really useless)
   if x ~= x_new then
      x:copy(x_new)
   end

   -- select a new training sample
   _nidx_ = (_nidx_ or 0) + 1
   if _nidx_ > (#data)[1] then _nidx_ = 1 end

   local sample = data[_nidx_]
   local target = sample[{ {1} }]      -- this funny looking syntax allows
   local inputs = sample[{ {2,3} }]    -- slicing of arrays.
   dl_dx:zero()
   local loss_x = criterion:forward(model:forward(inputs), target)
   model:backward(inputs, criterion:backward(model.output, target))
   return loss_x, dl_dx
end
```

I have a few doubts in this function

1. Where is the argument x_new (or its copy x) used in the code?
2. What does    `_nidx_ = (_nidx_ or 0) + 1` mean?
3. what is the value of *nidx* when the function is first called?
4. Where is dl_dx updated? Ideally it should have been just after *local loss_x*  is updated, but it isnt written explicitly

EDIT:

My point#4 is very clear now. For those who are interested-
(source- deep learning, oxford, practical 3 lab sheet)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the argument x_new (or its copy x) used in the code?

`x` is the tensor of parameters of your model. It was previously acquired via `x, dl_dx = model:getParameters()`. `model:forward()` and `model:backward()` automatically use this parameter tensor. `x_new` is a new set of parameters for your model and is provided by the optimizer (SGD). If it is ever different from your model's parameter tensor, your model's parameters will be set to these new parameters via `x:copy(x_new)` (in-place copy of tensor's `x_new` values to `x`).

> What does  *nidx* = (*nidx* or 0) + 1 mean?

It increases the value of `_nidx_` by `1` (`(_nidx_) + 1`) or sets it to `1` (`(0) + 1`) if `_nidx_` was not yet defined.

> what is the value of nidx when the function is first called?

It is never set before that function. Variables which were not yet set have the value `nil` in lua.

> Where is dl_dx updated? Ideally it should have been just after local loss_x is updated, but it isnt written explicitly

`dl_dx` is the model's tensor of gradients. `model:backward()` computes the gradient per parameter given a loss and adds it to the model's gradient tensor. As `dl_dx` is the model's gradient tensor, its values will be increases. Notice that the gradient values are *added*, which is why you need to call `dl_dx:zero()` (sets the values of `dl_dx` in-place to zero), otherwise your gradient values would keep increasing with every call of `feval`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `x` is a global variable, see line 126. The function only seems to update it, not to use it.
2. This is a common lua idiom: you set things to a parameter or a default value if it is not present. Typical use in functions:

   ```
   function foo(a, b)
       local a = a or 0
       local b = b or "foo"
   end
   ```

The idea is that an expression using `and` or `or` evaluates to the first or the second argument, according to the values. `x and y` yields `y` if `x` is not `nil` or `false` and `x` (nil or false) otherwise.

`x or y` yields `y` if `x` is not present (nil or false) and `x` otherwise. Therefore, `or` is used for default arguments.

The two can be rewritten the following way:

```
-- x and y
if x then
    return y
else
    return x
end
-- x or y
if x then
    return x
else
    return y
end
```

3. you have `_nidx_ =  (_nidx or 0) + 1`, so at the first call of the function, `_nidx_` is nil, since it has been defined nowhere. After that, it is (globally) set to 1 (0 + 1)
4. I'm not sure what you mean exactly. It is reset in line 152 and returned by the function itself. It is a global variable, so maybe there is an outer use for it?

Comment: Thanks !
Another thing. When i run the file only upto line 126, -->
x, dl_dx = model:getParameters()

x and dl_dx seem to have some values. And each time i run, its a different value. Is x initialized randomly? and dl_dx computed accordingly to that x ?

Comment: 4. What i mean was, this function returns 2 things- loss_x and dl_dx.         
And we assign the value loss_x. This is the loss function of SGD for training example #_nidx_  -     

   `local loss_x = criterion:forward(model:forward(inputs), target)`
              

but where is dl_dx assigned its value? (the gradient of SGD)
            
my guess was the next line computes the dl_dx-
        
`model:backward(inputs, criterion:backward(model.output, target))`
         
But this value is not **assigned** to dl_dx. Does this happen automatically?

Comment: Sorry, i can't help you with that, since i don't know torch. I can only help you with directly lua-related questions. Maybe alejus answer can help?

Comment: yea i read his answer now and things seem be much better. Thanks :D